# PHP function not selecting data and showing mysql_num_rows from database

Tags: php

I am using this PHP function:

```
if(!function_exists("SelectQuery")) {
    function SelectQuery ($sql) {
        global $conn;
        $SelectQuery = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        $SelectQuery_Results=array();
        while($SelectQuery_Row = mysql_fetch_array($SelectQuery)) {
            $SelectQuery_Results[] = $SelectQuery_Row;
        }
        return $SelectQuery_Results;
    }
}
```

and then trying to call it here:

```
$sql="SELECT * from tickets where ticketnumber = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
$ticket = SelectQuery($sql);
foreach($ticket as $ticket) {
    echo mysql_num_rows($ticket);
}
```

but it is coming up with this error:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /home/integra/public_html/admin/helpdesk/reviewtickets.php on line 101
```

what am i doing wrong?

if i do echo `$ticket["sequence"];` that works, just the `mysql_num_rows($ticket);` isnt working

Comment: changes as `foreach($ticket as $tic) {`

Comment: check my edit at the bottom

Comment: what is the result of SelectQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach loop:

```
foreach($ticket as $t) {
    echo mysql_num_rows($t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass mysql_query() result to mysql_num_rows().

```
$SelectQuery = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
echo mysql_num_rows($SelectQuery);
```